# Wolf Form - one or two damage?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In the third edition the Rules Reference book states that using Wolf Form causes Dracula to take one damage, but the rulebook and Wolf Form card both state two damage. Is this is an error in the rules reference book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It doesn't matter.

The section in the first page of [the Rules Reference from FFG itself](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/fury-of-dracula/), titled *Golden Rules* says

> This Rules Reference is the definitive source of rules 
>   information. If something in the Rules Reference 
>   contradicts the Learn to Play booklet, this document takes 
>   precedence.
>
> If the rules text of a card or game component contradicts 
>   information from the Rules Reference, the component-
>   specific rules text takes precedence.

Thus a hierarchy of correctness is established, so that the "most correct" statement is whatever the card itself says.

**The card says two damage. Dracula takes two damage. End of story.**

Answer (score 0):

In my printed English version of the game all references (card, RR, LtP) mention only **one** damage.

This is also true for downloadable PDFs:
[Learn to Play](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/59/64/59640173-626d-46fc-b3bc-c19405d49b00/gw09_learn_to_playcompressed.pdf) and [Rules Reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/b2/f6/b2f6ecf3-0b67-4beb-a4f9-4a33659e139b/gw09_rules_referencecompressed.pdf)
as well as stated in [Errata](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/47/b7/47b7b483-17b1-4724-a404-0889774f84f6/furyofdracula_faq_v10.pdf).